# How can I load a type definition from AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-sdk

I'm using `aws-sdk` and I have:

```
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({region: 'us-east-1'})

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    async find(): Promise<any[]> {
        const SECRET_CREDENTIALS = await secretsmanager.getSecretValue({ SecretId: 'Secrets' }).promise()
        const SECRET_CREDENTIALS_PARSED = JSON.parse(SECRET_CREDENTIALS.SecretString)

        let identities = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers({
            UserPoolId: SECRET_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.COGNITO_POOL
        }).promise()


        return identities.Users
    }

}
```

I want to set the type properly. How can I import the `ListUsersResponse` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing `ListUsersResponse`:

`import {ListUsersResponse} from 'aws-sdk/clients/cognitoidentityserviceprovider';`

---

Other types of potential interest can be imported from this same location.  An illustration based on the code in the question:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import {ListUsersResponse, UserType} from 'aws-sdk/clients/cognitoidentityserviceprovider';
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()

export class UsersService {
    async find(): Promise<UserType[]> { 
        let identities = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers({
            UserPoolId: "<USER_POOL>"
        })
        .promise()
        .then((result: ListUsersResponse) => result);

        return identities.Users
    }
}
```